# Elements not appearing after a background image

Tags: html, css, background

I've added a background image to my site, added some text to it and decided to add a button looking "" element but for some reason, the  element does not appear, nor do other elements like h1, etc. any idea why?

```css
.logo a {
    background: url("../img/pocitac.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 658px;
    width: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: relative;
    top: -21px;
    
    
}
.mainlogo {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.kidos {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -400px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 65px;
    line-height: 55Px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: 200;
    bottom: 60px;

}

.button {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed",sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="mainlogo">
      <h1 class="logo">
         <a href="#">Logo</a>
      <h1 class="kidos">WE CRAFT INSPIRING <br> DIGITAL EXPERIENCES</h1>
        <a href="#">THIS TEXT DOES NOT APPEAR</a>
      <h1>This one neither</h1>
    </div>

    

</body>
</html>
```

Image of what I am seeing only
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGeKC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can see you’re just getting started with HTML & CSS so I’ll give you a few pointers.

**First off** you’re HTML is all over the place, so lets start there:

- You’re using `<h1 class="logo">` as a container of sorts, so you probably shouldn’t be using a h1 element. Use a `div` here and then put your `h1` title & links inside that (you also haven’t closed this tag which will cause problems)

What you want is one container with the background image applied to it, then another centered container with your text and links in

**Second**, lets look at your CSS:

- text-indent: -9999px; - this basically move the first line of text in by x many pixels, you’re applying it to all the `a` tags inside any element with the `logo` class so those links are going to be -9999 pixels to the left, offscreen
- Look up how position:relative and position:absolute work - you should be setting a parent as relative and then a child as absolute, then you can use top/left/right/bottom to place the child relative to the parent
- it's not breaking anything here, but you've got `z-index: 9;` applied to your button - z-index is used for layering elements that have a `position` CSS property applied, since your button doesn't, this isn't doing anything

Here's a simplified example of what i think you're going for - don't just copy paste it, have a look over it and try to figure out where you've gone wrong

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLB85STTAN4E